# Assign values of list to another list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list that gets the values from a xml file. The list contains values from 0 to 6 and the values repeat.
Now I need to assign different names to the list like below:

0 = sunday,
1 = monday,
.
.
.
6 = saturday

The final list must be updated with sunday, monday etc..

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: stackoverflow is _not_ a free code-writing service

Comment: Can you post what have u tried so far. any code?

Comment: I'm asking for idea, not code

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Linq*: in your current case you can *cast* each number in `0..6` range into `DayOfWeek` and then get name via `.ToString()`:

```
  List<int> source = new List<int>() { 0, 3, 1, 5 };

  List<string> result = source
    .Select(item => ((DayOfWeek)item).ToString())
    .ToList(); 

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", result));
```

Outcome

```
  Sunday, Wednesday, Monday, Friday
```

In *general* case use mapping:

```
  Dictionary<int, string> map = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    {0, "sunday"},
    {1, "monday"},
    {2, "tuesday"},
    {3, "wednesday"},
    {4, "thursday"}
    {5, "friday"},
    {6, "saturday"},   
  }; 

  ...

  List<string> result = source
    .Select(item => map[item])
    .ToList();
```

Finally, if you want to add into *existing* `List<T>` put `AddRange` and drop `ToList()`:

```
  List<string> result = ...

  ...

  result.AddRange(source.Select(item => map[item]));
```